# jquery clone with different id elements

Tags: jquery

I have this form containing input fields.I wanted to clone element with different id or name if possible.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Item Name</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Rate</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Discount</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Tax %</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody-row">
                    <tr id="items-row">
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group">

                                <input type="text" name="Inv_Itemsdetail" value="" class="Itemsdetail-typeahead" autocomplete="on" data-provide="typeahead" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="Inv_Itemsdetail" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#cardCode05"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.quantity, new { @Class = "form-control", min = "1", id = "txtqty", type = "number" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.rate, new { @Class = "form-control", id = "txtrate", disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.discount, new { @Class = "form-control", id = "txtdiscount" })</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group">

                                <input type="text" name="Inv_Taxes" value="" class="Taxes-typeahead" autocomplete="on" data-provide="typeahead" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="Inv_Taxes" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modalterm" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @Class = "form-control", id = "txtamt", disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                    </tr>



            </table>
```

I have given this row an id and able to generate different id of this row element.
But problem happens to be true when I want to change id of textboxes inside this row.

**jQuery-**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#add-item').click(function () {
                    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
                    var $itemrow = $('#items-row>td>.Itemsdetail-typeahead');
                    $itemrow.attr('class', 'autocomplete' + num);
                    $('#items-row').clone().attr("Id", "row_" + num).appendTo('#tbody-row');


                });
            });

        </script>
```

Here you can see cloning is being happened on row element but not on input textboxes under this row. I want to clone with different id of every element inside this row.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#items-row').clone()
```

Here by default(*false*) will clone the entire element with its attributes.

check [.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents) for its definitions.

So change it to

```
$('#items-row').clone(true, true);
$('#items-row').prop('id', "row_" + num);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are producing a new `ID` randomly? I suggest you do it by this way

```
// simply get the last tr index and icrease it
var num = $('.table-bordered tbody tr:last-child').index() + 1;
```

Second, your visible `input` elements dont have `ID`s so i guess you wanna do this on `hidden inputs`? You can do it placing this code after the cloning line

```
$('.table-bordered tbody tr:last-child input[id=Inv_Itemsdetail]').attr("id","Inv_Itemsdetail_" + num);
$('.table-bordered tbody tr:last-child input[id=Inv_Taxes]').attr("id","Inv_Taxes" + num);
```